# MYSQL : Multiple clauses in set value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to produce a code like this :

```
`UPDATE location as l INNER JOIN location_instance as i ON l.lid=i.lid INNER JOIN node as n ON n.nid = i.nid 
        SET 'l.name=n.title', 
            'l.street =TABLEX.VALUEX WHERE TABLEX.nid = n.nid'
            'l.city = TABLEY.VALUEY WHERE TABLEY.nid = n .nid`
```

But i'm not sure about the part involving the SET command. :

```
`'l.street =TABLEX.VALUEX WHERE TABLEX.nid = n.nid'
 'l.city = TABLEY.VALUEY WHERE TABLEY.nid = n .nid`
```

Can anyone help me fix this out ?

Thanks,

Comment: Use the same approach you used with `node`.

Comment: why don't you `join` TABLEX and TABLEY before the SET statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the tables (`TABLEX` and `TABLEY`) in or use a subquery.  For instance:

```
UPDATE location l INNER JOIN
       location_instance i
       ON l.lid = i.lid INNER JOIN
       node n ON n.nid = i.nid 
   SET l.name = n.title, 
       l.street = (SELECT TABLEX.VALUEX FROM TABLEX WHERE TABLEX.nid = n.nid),
       l.city = (SELECT TABLEY.VALUEY FROM TABLEY WHERE TABLEY.nid = n.nid);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is as:

```
UPDATE location as l INNER JOIN location_instance as i ON l.lid=i.lid INNER JOIN node as n ON n.nid = i.nid 
        SET l.name=n.title, 
            l.street =TABLEX.VALUEX 
            l.city = TABLEY.VALUEY
 WHERE TABLEY.nid = n .nid and TABLEX.nid = n.nid
```

Comment: Is the second line of the above SET missing a comma at the end (after =TABLEX.VALUEX)?